# Topological sort, but with a certain kind of grouping

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

It seems this must be a common scheduling problem, but I don't see the solution or even what to call the problem. It's like a topological sort, but different....

Given some dependencies, say

```
A -> B -> D -- that is, A must come before B, which must come before D
A -> C -> D
```

there might be multiple solutions to a topological sort:

```
    A, B, C, D
and A, C, B, D
```

are both solutions.

I need an algorithm that returns this:

```
(A) -> (B,C) -> (D)
```

That is, do A, then all of B and C, then you can do D. All the ambiguities or don't-cares are grouped.

I think algorithms such as those at [Topological Sort with Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073119/topological-sort-with-grouping) won't correctly handle cases like the following.

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
A - - - > M - - - > E
```

For this, the algorithm should return

```
(A) -> (B, C, D, M) -> (E)
```

This

```
A -> B -> D -> F
A -> C -> E -> F
```

should return

```
(A) -> (B, D, C, E) -> (F)
```

While this

```
A -> B -> D -> F
A -> C -> E -> F
     C -> D
     B -> E
```

should return

```
(A) -> (B, C) -> (D, E) -> (F)
```

And this

```
A -> B -> D -> F
A -> C -> E -> F
A -> L -> M -> F
     C -> D
     C -> M
     B -> E
     B -> M
     L -> D
     L -> E
```

should return

```
(A) -> (B, C, L) -> (D, E, M) -> (F)
```

Is there a name and a conventional solution to this problem? (And do the algorithms posted at [Topological Sort with Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073119/topological-sort-with-grouping) correctly handle this?)

**Edit to answer requests for more examples:**

```
A->B->C
A->C
```

should return

```
(A) -> (B) -> (C). That would be a straight topological sort.
```

And

```
A->B->D
A->C->D
A->D
```

should return

```
(A) -> (B, C) -> (D)
```

And

```
A->B->C
A->C
A->D
```

should return

```
(A) -> (B,C,D)
```

Comment: What is the expected answer for: A->B->C, A->C ?

Comment: Sorry to pester you, but how about A->B->D, A->C->D, A->D ?

Comment: Oh really! Last one!  A->B->C, A->C, A->D

Comment: (A) -> (B,C,D) is incorrect right? Because B->C ?

Comment: Can there be input like this A->B->C->D->E, A->M->F? The answer seems to be A->(B,C,D,E,M,F)?

Comment: I am not convinced your question is well-defined.  A->B->C plus A->C plus A->D gives A->(B,C,D)?  Which just drops the dependency between B and C by grouping them together?

Comment: The interpretation of `A -> B -> C -> D -> E; 
A -> M -> E` as `(A) -> (B, C, D, M) -> (E)` seems highly suspect to me.  The answer says 'the order of B, C, and D does not matter'; the data says 'B must precede C, and C must precede D'.

Comment: Yes, some dependencies in the original graph will be lost in the result. DenIs is right in his example.

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004973/algorithm-for-computing-partial-orderings-of-dependency-graphs/5057093#5057093

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let G be the transitive closure of the graph. Let G' be the undirected graph that results from removing the orientation from G and taking the complement. The connected components of the G' are the sets you are looking for.

Comment: OK, now I need to figure out what that means. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Now I understand it. And now I need to figure out how to code it in XSLT. Thanks wye-bee!